# Connecting to Amazon Aurora with Laravel in production

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services

I've developed a Laravel app locally and connected locally to a database instance of Amazon Aurora. Had no problems connected to that DB locally but now that I've migrated to production, I get a 
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '[AMAZON AURORA URL HERE]' (4)

error. I'm hosting on MediaTemple. I've got the database access on Amazon set to public, so not sure why I wouldn't be able to connect using the same settings I'm connecting to locally.

Comment: That error usually means the connection was refused - a firewall on the MediaTemple side may be be blocking outgoing packets with that destination port. You could try `nmap -p 3306 <aws url>` from the server to see if the port is open.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check your inbound security group settings.

When you create a new RDS instance, the launch wizard automatically creates a security group that allows your local IP (so it makes sense you've been able to log-in on your local dev).

Make sure to go in to that security group and also add the CIDR/IP of your MediaTemple server.